# What to call this kind of symmetry in a sphere?

Tags: geometry, terminology, symmetry

Geometrically, if the two hemispheres of a spherical distribution of some kind (let's say a spherical gas cloud) are similar such that the properties of the gas as seen by a person standing on a circle dividing the two hemispheres would see the same exact properties whether they looked up or down, does that kind of symmetry have a name?  I would guess either equitorial symmetry or hemispheric symmetry but I don't know if those have different meanings than what I am trying to describe.

Comment: What does "diving" mean in this context?

Comment: This question is not mathematically well defined. What do you mean by "see"? There are inherent symmetries of spheres, not "visible" to the human eye.

Comment: @rubberchicken I think it is a misspelling of ‘dividing’.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar I changed the question in an effort to be more specific about what I mean.  I apologize if it is not well-enough defined mathematically to make sense.  If so, would someone who has a more well-defined description of what I'm trying to say put forth their description?

Comment: Do you mean if you cut the sphere by arbitrary plane (passing throught the origin) into two hemispheres, the "integral" of the density over the two hemispheres is always the same?

Comment: Not an arbitrary plane, a specific one that divides the sphere into two hemispheres with the "integral" of the density over the two hemispheres is always the same, whereas other planes may not cause the two hemispheres to exhibit the same symmetry in properties.

Comment: Let's say you choose the coordinate axis such that this specific plane is the $x-y$ plane. When you say "it is the same when you looking up and down", do you mean the density at $(x,y,z)$ on the sphere is the same as that on $(x,y,-z)$? If that's is what you mean, then this is called "reflection symmetry".

Comment: @achillehui: Yes, that is what I mean.  Is there any way I can be more specific in describing this symmetry than just "reflection symmetry"?  Would I say "reflection symmetry over the $x-y$ plane"?

Comment: A reflection is fully specified by the corresponding plane. if you say something like the distribution is symmetric with respect to reflection of the so-and-so plane and fully describe which plane you are referring to, then it is unambiguous.

Comment: @achillehui: If you want to be awarded the bounty I suggest writing a full answer instead of just a comment.